# data transformation for timestamp in event log

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with transaction_id, activity_name and time.

1. If you look closely at the data, you will see that there are
   almost always two subsequent rows that share the same ​ActivityName​
   and ​Transaction_ID​. The first of two rows is always the start and
   the second is the complete time of an event. How to combine two
   subsequent rows for the same activity into one with start and
   complete timestamp?
2. Also, for example if in some cases the last
   event of such an activity in a case comes from something that has
   only been started but not yet completed. How to remove all rows for
   which we do not have a matching second row. This is example of given
   dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TransID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                   'ActivityName': ['Request','Request','Start','Start','Schedule Activities'],
                'Timestamp':['2016-01-01 10:00:00', '2016-01-01 10:10:00','2016-01-01 10:10:00','2016-01-01 10:20:00','2016-01-01 10:20:00']})
df
```

And I need result such this:

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame({'TransID': [1, 1], 
                   'ActivityName': ['Request','Start'],
                'Timestamp':['2016-01-01 10:00:00', '2016-01-01 10:10:00'],
                'Timestamp_Complete':['2016-01-01 10:10:00','2016-01-01 10:20:00']})
df_res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
## Get unique combinations into a list
df_uniq = df[['TransID', 'ActivityName']].drop_duplicates()
uniq_combos = [[df_uniq.loc[x,'TransID'],df_uniq.loc[x,'ActivityName']] for x in df_uniq.index]
## Loop through the list and add rows to list
list1 = []
for tID, an in uniq_combos:
    df2 = df[(df.TransID==tID)&(df.ActivityName==an)].reset_index(drop=True)
    if len(df2) == 2:
        dict1 = {}
        dict1['TransID'] = tID
        dict1['ActivityName'] = an
        dict1['Timestamp'] = df2.loc[0,'Timestamp']
        dict1['Timestamp_Complete'] = df2.loc[1,'Timestamp']
        list1.append(dict1)
    else:
        pass
## Create df from list of dicts    
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
```